||A-B|| compared to the difference of their smallest singular values
I came cross a problem:
For two matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, if ${\rm rank}\ A = {\rm rank}\ B = r \leq \min \{m,n\}$, then
\begin{equation}
  |\sigma_r(A)  - \sigma_r(B) | \leq \|A - B\|_2,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_1(A) \geq \sigma_2(A) \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_r(A) > 0$, $\sigma_1(B) \geq \sigma_2(B) \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_r(B) > 0$ are the singular values of matrix $A$ and $B$ respectively.
My problem is how to prove the fact above.

It's a consequence of the Weyl inequalities for singular values: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/#kyfan

Thanks a lot @Kakashi.
